# Can a groovy build script class acces the Gradle project directly?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Can a groovy class (located in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy`) access the project directly, or does the project have to be passed in explicitly?

I am able to access the project by explicitly passing it in as a method parameter, but I do not want to have to pass it in. For an example, I would like to be able to get access to the project via a static method call. Is this type of implicit access possible?

**Explicit Access**

```
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyClazz {
    static void foo(Project project) {
        println project.version
    }
}
```

Task in build.gradle

```
task foo() << {
    MyClazz.foo(project)
}
```

**Implicit Access via Static Method Call** (this is the desired access pattern)

```
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyClazz {
    static void foo() {
        println Project.getProject().version
    }
}
```

Task in build.gradle

```
task foo() << {
    MyClazz.foo()
}
```

Comment: how do you call the script?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I updated the question to include the task in build.gradle

Comment: I think you understand it not worse than me - calling a method during task execution has no specific context. gradle API does not have Project.getProject() analogues so you either have to pass project in params or do the same thing before your actual task gets executed, in some service setup task.

Comment: You could instead write a plugin, then this can access project directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groovy extension methods to do this.

here's a self-contained example, but should work with Gradle too:

```
class Project {
    // we add this method dynamically
    //static getProject() { [ version: 2.3 ] }
}

class MyClazz {
    static void foo() {
        println Project.getProject().version
    }
}

class Gradle {

    static def main(args) {
        Project.metaClass.static.getProject = { [ version: 4.2 ] }
        MyClazz.foo()
    }

}
```